# How to tell function lock status in Dell XPS 15

Tags: dell, function-keys

I have a Dell XPS 15 laptop.
In order to change the function keys functionality (e.g. <kbd>F1</kbd> is used for mute, <kbd>F2</kbd> for volume down etc.)  I can lock the keys using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.
However, in oppose to other laptops where you have little light that shows you if the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button is locked or not, in the Dell it doesn't exist.
Can I show that (whether the <kbd>Fn</kbd> is locked or not) somehow on the screen or any other smart solution you can think of?

Comment: Don't think so. The operating system does not know about the Fn key.

Comment: This one of many things that I don't with my brand new XPS15-CoreI9. I for sure miss my old Lenovo X1. Anyone found a solution for this - Windows or Linux